How should you specify a bifactor SEM, where one factor only has one item?
I am trying to respecify an SEM in R using the lavaan package to improve model fit. After inspecting the standardized residuals I noticed that item injnorm2 is formulated in conjunctive (i.e. using would), while the other items for the norm factor aren't. I suspected that this could explain some of the residuals so I decided to create a con factor and let injnorm2 load on norm as well as con. To make sure that the model is still identified with a single-item factor I specified the residual variance of injnorm2 using the formula residual variance = (1 - reliability)*item variance and the reliability of injnorm2 from a previous study.
The code looks as follows:
tpb_cfa_re <- 'att =~ attitude1 + attitude2 + attitude
               norm =~ injnorm1 + injnorm2 + injnorm3
               pbcon =~ pbc2 + pbc3
               redint =~ intention1 + intention2 + intention3

               con =~ injnorm2
               con ~~ 0*norm
               injnorm2 ~~ 0.259*injnorm2
'
fit_tbp_cfa_re <- cfa(model = tpb_cfa_re,
                      data = Indikatoren,
                      effect.coding = "loadings", # Coding Effects Method Constraints
                      estimator = "MLR",
                      missing " "FIML")

I wonder if this approach is appropriate since the variance I specified for injnorm2 depends on the reliability this item had for norm in a previous study. The reliability of injnorm2 is, however, likely much lower for con. If I wanted the variance of injnorm2 to be freely estimated I assume I would have to set the factor variance of con so the model is still identified.
Therefore my question is: Is this approach of setting the residual variance of injnorm2 valid? And if not is there an appropriate way to guess what the factor variance of con would be so it could be set instead?

It is probably rather difficult to make a guess about the variance of the specific factor  (con) without prior knowledge. Likewise, as you mention, the reliability/error variance estimate from a separate study/sample may not be applicable here for a variety of reasons. A more reasonable solution may be to specify the injnorm2 indicator as reference indicator for the substantive factor (norm) and to include a specific (or "method") factor for the two other items (injnorm1 and injnorm3; with both loadings fixed to 1 for identification). That way, you would not have to make a guess regarding the variances. However, this would turn the norm factor into an injnorm2-specific factor. Whether or not this makes sense for you is a substantive question (i.e., can injnorm2 be seen as a marker indicator for the norm construct?).

This helped a lot! It works theoretically, too. (BTW Your YouTube videos on SEMs are very informative too)

I'm so glad it helped. Good luck with your work! Christian Geiser
